# Ubuntu Terminal Badges?

Tags: command-line, 18.04

Is there an option like in iTerm2 to have [badges](https://www.iterm2.com/documentation-badges.html) (red text in the image)?

[image: iterm2 with badge]

Comment: Which terminal emulator do you use?

Comment: To simulate the effect you could use `osd_cat` from the `xosd-bin` package, e.g. `osd_cat -Aright -f"-*-*-*-*-*-*-100-*-*-*-*-*-*-*" <<<test`, and run a script displaying the information you want as a background process in the shell.

Comment: Hmm doesnt work on Ubuntu 18.04 - just shows blank

Comment: Works for me on Kubuntu 18.04 – did you install the package with `sudo apt install xosd-bin` first? If you don’t use `bash` as your shell, try `echo test | osd_cat -Aright -f"-*-*-*-*-*-*-100-*-*-*-*-*-*-*"` instead.

Comment: Yes I did - sudo apt-get install xosd-bin - apperently I am not using bash o.O - tho I did not change it. This works but puts the echo in my screen - can I get it to stay in the terminal and also for the whole time?

Comment: On second thought it’s a heck of a task to write a script for that – not only the positioning is a problem, but also different tabs (I guess your terminal emulator has this feature), and then you’ll want the OSD text to be minimised with the terminal window… I don’t say it’s impossible, but it’s certainly a challenge.